# Get return value of function javascript on webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a javascript function:

```
function getData(){
   return document.getElementById("xx").value;
}
```

I use `HtmlElement` to append code in html and use webbrowser `invokescript` to run function `getData()`.

I want to get return value of `getData()` and show it on messageBox.

Comment: is it  a function which aleardy exits on the site?

Comment: It not exits on the site. I use HtmlElement to append it in code. I can run it but i don't know to get return value of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply assign it into a string variable

```
  String str = doc.InvokeScript("getData").ToString();
```